# Show center area of image with maximum size css

Tags: html, css

[Image](https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/13712196_1641293696198429_1628634962_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxNDE4MzE0NTczMDMzODQ1Mw%3D%3D.2),

This image's dimension is 320 x 238. I want to show the image in 179 x 179px. I want the image NOT to skew and it needs to capture the most area with center contents. Is that possible using CSS?

My HTML:

```
<span class="each_project">
    <figure>
     <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/13712196_1641293696198429_1628634962_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxNDE4MzE0NTczMDMzODQ1Mw%3D%3D.2" alt=""></a>
    </figure>

</span>
```

My span properties are:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
floatleftfont-family: "Lato";
font-size: 16px;
height: 179px;
line-height: 24px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 179px;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of - get rid of `span` and use `div` instead. You should use `span` for text, not as element's block; All you need to do is set width and height of your parent element to 179 x 179px and use `trasnform` on the image. Working example:

```css
.each_project {
  width: 179px;
  height: 179px;
}
.each_project img {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="each_project">
  <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/13712196_1641293696198429_1628634962_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxNDE4MzE0NTczMDMzODQ1Mw%3D%3D.2" alt="">
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

I've put a `border` to this example, so you can see, that is is centered. I didn't get it for the first time, but hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
.each_project {
  width: 179px;
  height: 179px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.each_project.larger {
  width: 300px;
}
.each_project .image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/13712196_1641293696198429_1628634962_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMxNDE4MzE0NTczMDMzODQ1Mw%3D%3D.2');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="each_project">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>

<div class="each_project larger">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to do it without background image. I'm fetching it from Instagram and I have multiple of these which needs in a loop.

Comment: This is the fastest way (I think) and will works on all major browsers. If it would be with `<img>` element, then you will need JavaScript help. But you can use inline style, like `<div class="image" style="background-image: url('.........'):"></div>` which will have same effect in the loop. At least, when I need something like that, I use inline style.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this:

```
span img {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.each_project {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  floatleftfont-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 179px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 179px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.each_project img {
  margin: -100%;
}
```